# What is the best USB coffee warmer

Tags: coffee-culture, cup

What is the best USB coffee warmer?

I find that I take way too long to drink my coffee and it gets cold. I usually take more than an hour per cup.

What do you recommend for best usb coffee warmer.

Comment: I struggle with a blank “the best”. Without details, this is about as opinion-based as it gets. (And that’s not even considering the problem of coffee that’s been too warm for too long - *shudders*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Turns out](https://youtu.be/yqgKlqAUM9g), it's not heat which is the enemy of good coffee, but *too much* heat.

The best coffee warmer is one that keeps your coffee at a controlled drinking temperature. The problem with a thermos is that it will keep the coffee too hot for comfortable drinking initially. Reheating will burn the coffee.

So anything which keeps the coffee at around 50°C will be good. Product recommendations are off-topic here, but James Hoffmann recommends a specific mug in above linked video, although that seems a bit pricey to me (I actually only found it for about 200€).

Comment: I thought so because my Moccamaster also keeps my coffee warm and it doesn’t seem to affect the taste.  Thanks for recommending.

Comment: Heating liquids is a tricky science because the amount of heat you need depends on the volume of liquid and the thermal qualities of the vessel. A heated mug will overcome this by eliminating the vessel variable and controlling for liquid volume. A USB warmer, on the other hand, will work with two fundamental problems: first, it can't know how much heat it needs to provide, and second, it has access to only five volts with which to provide it. The result is typically underwhelming unless you're keeping warm 4 ounces of coffee in a single wall steel cup.

Comment: USB warmer worked a treat!

Answer (score 1):

Heat is the enemy of coffee.

I brew my coffee in a French press and then transfer it into a [carafe](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01LY5C1QB), the carafe keeps it from cooling down.

I only pour out 1/3 to 1/2 of a cup at a time.

No unnecessary use of electricity.

Comment: I suspected this would be the answer. I totally need to do this but the physical experience isn’t as satisfying

Comment: As satisfying as plugging something into a usb port? :)  What part of the experience do you think you will miss?

Comment: The part of not moving for 2 hours while reading my book and drinking coffee as part of my early bird routine ☺️

Comment: You do not have a servant to keep your cup filled. I am available for hire, i am not cheap, easy but not cheep.

Comment: Thanks, but you’re not my type.

Comment: I get that a lot.

Comment: For a cup (vs a full French press), a travel mug should also work?

Comment: Yes, any double walled stainless steel (or other very well insulated) container with a lid will work fine.